# Retrieve folder name of unknown folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bit of a nooby question.
I have created a python script and within it i need to find a folder name.
The structure of the folder system is like so:

C:/Folder_1/Folder_2/XxX

XxX is a dynamically named folder which uses date time structure.

Is there anyway to find the name of the folder XxX.

All i need to do is save it as a variable.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: use `Path` from `pathlib`

Comment: Why not use bash? `find . -name "XxX`?

Comment: use `basename = os.path.basename(path)`. see python documentation in th link [basename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)

Comment: @Adam your method what not work. 

If you imagine you had path C:/Blah... /Folder1/Folder2. And you dont know the name of folder 2. You can not find it with that method, to my knowledge

Comment: @KirkmanJ - read the question again. this is not what he asked for

Comment: As much as i Hate to argue, the line 'XxX is a dynamically named folder which uses date time structure.' Implies I do not know the folder name, sorry if my wording confused people

Answer (score 0):

For completion, a work around:

```
folder_location = 'C:/Folder_1/Folder_2/'
folders = os.listdir(folder_location )

for folder in folders :
    print(folder)
```